# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and export $DISPLAY to run graphical application

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, x-windows

If I SSH into a Raspberry Pi or into a local VM running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, then I can run:

```
user:~$ export DISPLAY=:0
user:~$ gedit
```

And this will open a graphical window on the OS with the text editor, gedit. However, if I SSH into an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I run "export DISPLAY=:0" followed by "gedit", I get these errors:

```
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:<proces id>): Gtk-WARNING **: <time stamp>: cannot open display: :0
```

Is there any way to find the display number, or any other way to launch a graphical application? Note that I *do not* want to forward a GUI window back to my terminal by passing for instance the -X flag.

Comment: Where do you want this gedit instance to display its window?

Answer (score 0):

Make the graphical session *write* its display number somewhere at login time.

For example, put these in your ~/.Xprofile:

```
echo "$DISPLAY" > ~/tmp/current-display
echo "$XAUTHORITY" > ~/tmp/current-xauthority
```

To make sure *everything* works, you should also repeat this with `$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, although they are frequently static on systemd-based systems, but not always.

Later you will be able to run:

```
export DISPLAY=$(< ~/tmp/current-display)
export XAUTHORITY=$(< ~/tmp/current-xauthority)
```

Note that `No protocol specified` frequently means that the display number was correct but that it *denied* the connection due to missing Xauth data.

Comment: I created ~/.Xprofile with those two lines and the directory ~/tmp, but at login no files get written to ~/tmp. There is a file .Xauthority with magic cookie data.